# Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server

Tags: c#, linux, ssl, tcp, mono

I'm trying to use TLS on over TCP sockets with a C# project that is suppose to run on Mono.

On Windows the project run just fine. On linux on Mono, the following error happens:

```
System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server.
```

I'm trying to import the root certificates with mozroots but it get certificates with everyone but Godaddy.

So how can I manually import the Godaddy CA certificates and which ones should I import and to which store in order to get away from this error and connect to the TCP server? (the root certs can be found here https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/)

Thanks!
Gutemberg

Comment: did you try with "mozroots --import --sync"? I believe this should get godaddy's cert as well since they are in Mozilla's list of trusted roots

Comment: Id doesn't, already tried that :(

Comment: The certmgr tool should let you import the godaddy certs from file, it ships with Mono.

Comment: hey Alex, do you know where are the sources of certmgr?